# how to scroll a both richTextbox and Panel with a custom Vscrollbar C#?

Tags: c#, scrollbar, panel, richtextbox

i am trying to scroll up and down both RTB and Panel with a single VscrollBar, i have textbox which is loaded with a text file and a panel which is loaded with the labels both textbox and panel should scroll with a single scrollbar i have searching around all over the internet but could not find any solution.
[figure is shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GfNdr.png)

Comment: Show us what you've got so far.

Comment: @javirs i am using Winform.

Comment: @ErikKralj i had applied interop services but could find it helpful. i have not applied any else yet.

Comment: never coded UI in winForm. I reomend switching to WPF :) Sorry cannot help any further

Answer (score 0):

assuming you are working on WPF you can encapsulate your items into an scrollViewer:

```
<ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
    <your RTB>
    <your labels>
</ScrollViewer>
```

I guess for WinForm you have something similar